# Xcode New "Run Script Phase" - How to handle output files?

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to add a `Run Script Phase` to my Build Phases to call a swift executable that takes a plist file from my project and uses it to generate a swift file with some boilerplate code.

I figured out how to specify the input file for the `Run Script Phase` like this:

```
$(SRCROOT)/MyProject/MyData.plist
```

But for output files, `Xcode` gives me this `$(DERIVED_FILE_DIR)/newOutputFile` default value which, if I echo it via `echo "$SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0"`, prints some strange path to the `....MyProject.build/DerivedSources` folder. What is that? What do I do with this and how can I generate my output swift file and place it inside my project?

I don't really find much information about this `$(DERIVED_FILE_DIR)` (at least nothing that I understand, I've never worked with these things before).

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to tell what the question is about. You might be looking for the `PROJECT_DIR` if the goal is to write stuff directly into your project.

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess the main point of my question is: Why does Xcode want to to use this $(DERIVED_FILE_DIR) Variable? What exactly is that directory and how is it connected to my project files? But also: Is it okay, to just not use that and set it to `$(PROJECT_DIR)/MyProject/MyOutputFile.swift`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Xcode want". I'm unaware of Xcode having desires.

Comment: When I click on the + icon in the "Output Files" List, it autofills `$(DERIVED_FILE_DIR)/newOutputFile` into a new entry inside the list and I suppose it does this because it wants the files to go to `$(DERIVED_FILE_DIR)` (aka "there's a reason they autofill this location. I don't understand it).

Comment: I suppose they just want to suggest a safe place to write to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the derived file directory is just a safe place to write output results to. It isn't in the project directory, but it is unique to the project.

However, you *do* want to write directly into the project directory (I presume), so just go ahead and do so, using the environmental variable `PROJECT_DIR`.